# jQuery compare values and alert

Tags: jquery

i have lot of same strings, but values like 1.05 are different

```
<div class="css-1m1f8hn">1.05</div>
<div class="css-1m1f8hn">1.07</div>
```

Can someone help me to check all values with this div class and if some value less then 1.05 make alert on jQuery like:
for each $( ".css-1m1f8hn" ) if value < 1.05 then alert('Less value found');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 
 $(".css-1m1f8hn").each((i,value) => {
   if(parseFloat($(value).html()) <  1.05) {
   alert('Less value found')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-1m1f8hn">1.05</div>
<div class="css-1m1f8hn">1.07</div>
<div class="css-1m1f8hn">1.02</div>
```

Comment: How i can change alert to play sound?

Comment: alert plays a sound only based on browser default behaviour. If you would wish to play a sound then there is a more complex way of doing it. You would need the sound file (.mp3)  check this link for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio